# Resolve Conflict When Using Highchart and Highmap together (TypeError: ma is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, conflicting-libraries, highmaps

I've a page that contain chart and map menu for report function. 
Then, I choose Highchart-Highmap library to reach the purpose above.
The chart function runs well but when I develop map function there's a error appear

> TypeError: ma is not a function

- I've traced the problem that the ma function is appear in highchart.js and highmaps.js but I don't know how to resolve this conflict.
- I've try put `jQuery.noConflict();` in highmaps but the conflict still appear

This how I code in main page

```
... some html code
<script type="text/javascript" src="././js/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="././js/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="././js/highcharts/highcharts-3d.js"></script>            
<script type="text/javascript" src="././js/highcharts/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="././js/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>

... some html code
<script type="text/javascript" src="././js/Highmaps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="././js/Highmaps/modules/data.js"></script>                
<script type="text/javascript" src="././js/Highmaps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Instead of highmaps, you need to use map.js module.

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

[Here is the documentation on using both together](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started).

Comment: I have done it in the same way. But Still getting error of missing some type of chart.

Below is the jsFiddle link. Please help me out.

http://jsfiddle.net/spidiweb/ad7spa3m/

Thanks,

Comment: Got the solution. I have to include highcharts-more.js for bubble chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/spidiweb/ad7spa3m/1/

Comment: Thanks! Saved my day!

Answer (score 5):

You must include this script tag after `highcharts.js`:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and resolved it by placing highcharts after the maps

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danny_shumer/tc898kgv/2/

Comment: Am getting Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16