# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'custom/world' of undefined

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am getting the error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'custom/world' of undefined", after changing my code from

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

I think there is some conflict with using highcharts and highmaps at the same time with custom/world,js. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try loading `http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js` instead of `highmaps.js`.

Comment: @HalvorStrand I also found out that url on the official website for using highcharts and highmaps at the same time, but the url seems to be broken. Thus, I followed the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230483/resolve-conflict-when-using-highchart-and-highmap-together-typeerror-ma-is-not. However, it doesn't solve the problem with custom/world.js.

Comment: Say you go to [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/tooltip/). It works fine. Then you add `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` to the top of the HTML. You get the error you mention. Then you replace the `highmaps.js` script with `https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js`, like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLs1ecse/). Then it dissapears and code works as expected. I think you'll have to show a specific case with code if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your highcharts.js version equals highmaps.js version ,use latest version is recommended.