# Not able to use Highmap with 3d highcharts in gwt

Tags: gwt, highcharts, highmaps

I want to use Highmaps with 3d highcharts but I am getting following exception

```
    com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(12317), JavaScript object(12316), JavaScript object(12578)]):

 d.align is undefined
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
        at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
        at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:356)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I want to show map on left side and 3d pie chart on right side but how to solve this problem? Can somebody help me with solution. I tried

[Resolve Conflict When Using Highchart and Highmap together (TypeError: ma is not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230483/resolve-conflict-when-using-highchart-and-highmap-together-typeerror-ma-is-not) but its not working..

My HTML file contains following scripts ::

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highsoft/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highsoft/highcharts-3d.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highsoft/drilldown.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highsoft/highcharts-more.js">/script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highsoft/data.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highsoft/map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highsoft/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: nobody is there to give a solution to this problem? or not using it?

Comment: You need share some code if you want help, sharing some errors is not enough. Can you make a JSFiddle showing the problem happening?

Comment: Thanks Roco actually I replaced all the JS to the latest version also changed highcharts.js to disable the legend and then removed legend property from the code where I have created the highmap(problem is with legend in the latest versions , highchart.js not version aligned with map.js ) then my code got worked... Thanks..